# How to automatically flatten and combine .csv files into one matrix in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a bunch of .csv files in Python that are x by y dimensions. I know how to flatten and reshape matrices, but am having trouble automatically doing this for multiple files. Once I have flattened the matrices into one dimension, I also would like to stack them on top of each other, in one big matrix.

Is this even the proper way to do a for loop? I have not gotten to the part of stacking the linearized matrices on top of each other into one matrix yet. Would that involve the DataFrame.stack() function? When I run the code below it gives me an error.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

file_list = sorted(os.listdir('./E/')) #created the list of files in a specific directory

del file_list[0] #removed an item from the list that I did not want

for file in range(0,26):
    pd.read_csv('./E/' + print(file_list), header=None) #should read files
    A = set(Int.flatten()) #should collapse matrix to one dimension
    B = np.reshape(A, -1) #should make it linear going across
```

Comment: Hi, please provide some data of the files (shortened) that all can see how exactly it looks like. And please show how the data should look like after your code run.

Comment: Additionally, if you could provide the error message, it would be helpful.

Comment: I think you're supposed to do `print(file)` instead of `print(file_list)`. `file_list` is, well, a list, and you can't make a file path with a list. I frankly don't know why you want the `print` around that -- you're trying to read a path, how is printing to the console supposed to help? Also, instead of `range(0, 26)`, you can do `range(len(file_list))` if you're planning to read every file in `file_list`.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know what your files look like, I'm not sure this will work. But still, the below code includes some concepts that should be useful:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

file_list = sorted(os.listdir('.\\E'))
del file_list[0]

# Eventually, all_files_array will contain len(file_list) elements, each of which is a file.
all_files_array = []

for i in range(len(file_list)):
    file = file_list[i]

    # Depending on how you saved your file, you may need to add index=None as an argument to read_csv.
    this_file_arr = pd.read_csv('.\\E\\' + file, header=None)

    # Change the dtype to int if that's what you're working with.
    this_file_arr = this_file_arr.to_numpy(dtype=float, copy=False)

    this_file_arr = np.unique(this_file_arr.flatten())

    # In all my tests, the following line does absolutely nothing, but I guess it doesn't hurt.
    this_file_arr = np.reshape(this_file_arr, -1)

    all_files_array.append(this_file_arr)

all_files_array = np.array(all_files_array)
# all_files_array now has shape (len(files_list), x, y) where one file has shape (x, y).
```

The main takeaways are that:

1. `os.listdir()` doesn't work when the path has slashes at the end. Also, Python requires that `/` in path names be replaced with '\', so I've done that.
2. Using `range` instead of hard-coding the number of files to read is good practice in case you add more files to `file_list` later down the line, unless of course you don't want to read all the files in `file_list`.
3. A `print` statement inside `pd.read_csv` is at best useless, and at worst will throw an error.
4. `this_file_arr.flatten()` is a NumPy method, so `this_file_arr` needs to be a NumPy array, hence the `to_numpy()` line.
5. Because `np.reshape` doesn't take sets, I used `np.unique` instead to avoid converting to a non-NumPy structure. If you want to use NumPy methods, keep your data in a NumPy array and don't convert it to a list or set or anything else.

Let me know if you have any questions!